# Left join with an id (number) on id in a String

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have two tables like this

Table Person

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Max |
| 11 | Ben |
| 12 | Luke |

Table Bike
(the person_id column is a varchar)

| bike_id | bike_name | Person_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hercules | 10 |
| 2 | Linx | 11, 12 |

Now I need a table like this

| id | name | bike_id | bike_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Max | 1 | Hercules |
| 11 | Ben | 2 | Linx |
| 12 | Luke | 2 | Linx |

I tried it with this SQL:

```
SELECT *  From Person person
 LEFT JOIN Bike bike
  ON (cast(person.id as varchar(10)) = bike.id);
```

And receive this table:

| id | name | bike_id | bike_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Max | 1 | Hercules |

I am using Oracle database.

Comment: ***Don't*** store multiple values as a delimited string...  Relational databases already have constructs for this; a `bike_person` table, with one row per association *(so, three rows in your case; `(1, 10)` and `(2, 11)` and `(2, 12)`)*.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a bad idea storing values as you do (talking about `bike.person_id` column).

One option to do what you want is to split `person_id` into rows and then perform join:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  person (id, name) as
  3    (select 10, 'Max'  from dual union all
  4     select 11, 'Ben'  from dual union all
  5     select 12, 'Luke' from dual
  6    ),
  7  bike (bike_id, bike_name, person_id) as
  8    (select 1, 'Hercules', '10'    from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'Linx'    , '11,12' from dual
 10    )
 11  --
```

Query begins here:

```
 12  select p.id, p.name, x.bike_id, x.bike_name
 13  from person p join
 14    (select b.bike_id, b.bike_name,
 15       regexp_substr(b.person_id, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) person_id
 16     from bike b cross join
 17       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 18                           connect by level <= regexp_count(b.person_id, ',') + 1
 19                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 20    ) x on x.person_id = p.id;

        ID NAME    BIKE_ID BIKE_NAM
---------- ---- ---------- --------
        10 Max           1 Hercules
        11 Ben           2 Linx
        12 Luke          2 Linx

SQL>
```

Comment: This is why I hate answering question on multiple values as delimited strings; the example data in the OP uses `', '` as the delimiter, not `','`, but whether that's due to formatting when they copied/typed the data, is unstated...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following join trick:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, b.bike_id, b.bike_name
FROM Bike b
INNER JOIN Person p
    ON ',' || b.Person_id || ',' LIKE '%,' || CAST(p.id AS varchar(10)) || ',%';
```

By the way, you should avoid storing CSV in the persons column.

**Edit:** If the `Person_id` column happens to be using comma followed by space as the separator, then use this version:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.name, b.bike_id, b.bike_name
FROM Bike b
INNER JOIN Person p
    ON ',' || REPLACE(b.Person_id, ' ', '') || ',' LIKE '%,' || CAST(p.id AS varchar(10)) || ',%';
```

Comment: This is why I hate answering question on multiple values as delimited strings; the example data in the OP uses `', '` as the delimiter, not `','`, but whether that's due to formatting when they copied/typed the data, is unstated...

Comment: @MatBailie Then strip off the spaces before doing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with newbike as
(
SELECT    bike_id,bike_name, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR (STR, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) SPLIT_VALUES  FROM bike 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT LENGTH (REPLACE (person_id, ',', NULL)) 
FROM TAB)
);

SELECT *  From Person person
 LEFT JOIN newbike bike
  ON person.id = bike.SPLIT_VALUES;
```

we can create new table with split value using this